# Reactor Flux: how to parse file with header

Tags: java, project-reactor

Recently I started using project reactor 3.3 and I don't know what is the best way to handle flux of lines, with first line as column names, then use those column names to process/convert all other lines. Right now I'm doing this way:

```java
Flux<String> lines = ....;
Mono<String[]> columns = Mono.from(lines.take(1).map(header -> header.split(";"))); //getting first line
Flux<SomeDto> objectFlux = lines.skip(1) //skip first line
  .flatMapIterable(row -> //iterating over lines
      columns.map(cols -> convert(cols, row)));  //convert line into SomeDto object
```

So is it the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is it the right way?

There's always more than one way to cook an egg - but the code you have there seems odd / suboptimal for two main reasons:

- I'd assume it's one line per record / DTO you want to extract, so it's a bit odd you're using `flatMapIterable()` rather than `flatMap()`
- You're going to resubscribe to `lines` once for each line, when you re-evaluate that `Mono`. That's almost certainly not what you want to do. (Caching the `Mono` helps, but you'd still resubscribe at least twice.)

Instead you may want to look at using [`switchOnFirst()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#switchOnFirst-java.util.function.BiFunction-), which will enable you to dynamically transform the `Flux` based on the first element (the header in your case.) This means you can do something like so:

```
lines
        .switchOnFirst((signal, flux) -> flux.zipWith(Flux.<String[]>just(signal.get().split(";")).repeat()))
        .map(row -> convert(row.getT1(), row.getT2()))
```

Note this is a bear-bones example, in real-world use you'll need to check whether the `signal` actually has a value as per the docs:

> Note that the source might complete or error immediately instead of emitting, in which case the Signal would be onComplete or onError. It is NOT necessarily an onNext Signal, and must be checked accordingly.

Comment: `You're going to resubscribe to lines once for each line` do you mean `columns`? Because you're also doing that, by definition that's what `repeat` does.

Comment: @123 Eh? `repeat()` is only called on the `Flux.just(signal.get().split(";"))` publisher - I don't consider multiple subscriptions to that an issue. That won't cause a re-subscription to `lines`. (I'm assuming `lines` here is a publisher obtaining those lines from a network or file somewhere, in which case re-subscribing isn't ideal.)

Comment: Ah get ya, misunderstood what you were getting at.

Comment: @MichaelBerry thx for your response and explanation. With your example i still need to skip the header but otherwise, it works like a charm and even faster as before :)